# Does mysql_connect() not work with 000webhost

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted confirmation if you can't use MySQL_connect with [000webhost](http://www.000webhost.com/).

They say the "remote connections" to MySQL are disabled, but I couldn't find what "remote connection" really means after doing some research. Does anyone know for sure if it won't work?

Comment: Where is the database located that you want to connect to? If the database is on the server provided to you by 000webhost then you can connect to it without needing a "remote connection."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remote connections are different from your API.

```
mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
```

Is alot different from:

*Your Server IP:* 98.568.321.210  For example.

```
mysql_connect("98.568.321.210","user","password");
```

The second example is blocked because you are attempting make a connection from a **remote** server, which is not localhost/127.0.0.1

So overall, yes although not recommended, you can use `mysql_*` functions.

I would recommend looking into `mysqli` or `pdo`  due to mysql being depreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to PHP, but 000webhost says not to use localhost, I might go trying new things, I just want to connect to a database and edit that database for a login system. I've resorted to text documents, which is horrible but the only way.

Comment: Oh yes. I have used 000 before, they give you a specific mysql address which you use in placement for `localhost`, or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Yeah, and that isn't working, thank you for the fast response. Could I store data in text documents?

Comment: By `isn't working` can you specify how? and what information will you be storing into your text documents? because just remember, you can instruct PHP to read the contents of the doc. But you wont stop users navigating to your text page and reading your database information.

Comment: You could nest them above the web root but really, if your host doesn't support databases at all then maybe you should look for a new host. Resorting to text files seems like a ridiculous alternative to just figuring out the problem, or - god forbid - asking 000webhost directly. Every host has support.

Comment: @KaiQing I can confirm that 000webhost do support mysql databases, no remote connections from external servers.. They do allow the use of mysql_*, mysqli, pdo and sqlsrv drivers;

Comment: I'm not saying they don't. I'm saying resorting to text just cause your initial attempts fail is a horrible solution to a problem that could be fixed just by asking them for instructions. Not to be a jerk, but it is also kind of ridiculous to post on SO before asking them as well.

Comment: @KaiQing We know your not a jerk

Comment: @KaiQing I agree with you about the text documents, I want to do everything in my power not to use them. I'll look in to MySQL_*, mysqli, etc, etc.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a database with 000webhost
you will be given  connection details similar to this

```
$mysql_host = "xxxx000webhost.com";
$mysql_database = "xxx_xxx";
$mysql_user = "xxx_xxx";
$mysql_password = "xxxx";
```

Save these in a file called dbinfo.php

Connecting to database using  [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

```
<?php
require_once("dbinfo.php");
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_host;dbname=$mysql_database", $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must allowed your host (your IP) into the mysql user settings from the target host

[MySQL user Add Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/adding-users.html)

Comment: I don't think they let any IP address access their databases, which I believe is a remote connection.